# How can I programmatically get the canonical unicode name of a character?

Tags: elisp, characters

I'm attempting to get the name of the character (or multibyte character) at point, and just the name, programmatically.

`describe-char` tells me what the character's name is, along with a bunch of other stuff that I don't want.

`get-char-property` appears to be what I want, except that I tell what property I want. Neither `'name`, `'Name`, `"Name"`, or `"name"` seem to do anything (when used as e.g. `(get-char-property ?& 'name)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From digging around in the source code for `describe-char`, `get-char-code-property` seems to be the right function:

```
(get-char-code-property ?& 'name)
"AMPERSAND"
```

Comment: Could you expand a little on how you found it? I dug around in there, but couldn't get much useful.

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful by searching for `name`, so I searched for the header above the name, `Character code properties`, and there it was.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from @legoscia works only some of the time. It does not work for control characters, including code points between 0 and 32. They don't have a `name` in the Unicode database.  But they do have an `old-name`.

In Unicode, surrogate code points, private-use characters, control codes, noncharacters, and unassigned code points have no names.

What you want to try in general is this:

```
(or (get-char-code-property SOME-CHAR 'name)
    (get-char-code-property SOME-CHAR 'old-name))
```

And keep in mind that some some code points do not even have an `old-name`.